# SQL - PostgreSQL - Find gaps in booking calendar

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, calendar

I am currently setting up a web based system to allow users to find availabilities of boats in a calendar.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6

A user should be able to say I want to find a boat available for three hours in the next three months between 08h00 in the morning and 16h00.

My current data model is the following.

```
 CREATE TABLE cal_calendar (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL
 , start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
 , time_range TSRANGE NOT NULL
);
```

The cal_calendar table has a TSRANGE column with a granularity of 15 minutes and contains:

```
  id  |     start_time      |                  time_range
------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 4225 | 2017-02-14 00:00:00 | ["2017-02-14 00:00:00","2017-02-14 00:15:00")
 4226 | 2017-02-14 00:15:00 | ["2017-02-14 00:15:00","2017-02-14 00:30:00")
 4227 | 2017-02-14 00:30:00 | ["2017-02-14 00:30:00","2017-02-14 00:45:00")
 4228 | 2017-02-14 00:45:00 | ["2017-02-14 00:45:00","2017-02-14 01:00:00")
 4229 | 2017-02-14 01:00:00 | ["2017-02-14 01:00:00","2017-02-14 01:15:00")
```

This table contains basicaly a reference calendar with all the 15 minutes periods over the next 5 years.

To populate the cal_calendar table I use the following Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use DBI;
use DateTime;

my $database = "mydatabase";
my $db_host = "localhost";
my $db_user = "nobody";
my $db_passwd = "noneofyourbusiness";
my $years_to_populate = $ARGV[0];

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=".$database.";host=".$db_host, $db_user, $db_passwd, {'RaiseError' => 0});

my $start_time = DateTime->new( year  => 2016, month => 12, day   => 31, hour => 23, minute => 45);
my $end_time = $start_time->clone->add(years => $years_to_populate);

my $i=1;     
while ( $start_time->add(minutes => 15) < $end_time ) {

  my $period_start= $start_time->strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );
  my $period_end = $start_time->clone->add(minutes => 15)->strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );
  $dbh->do("INSERT INTO cal_calendar (id, start_time, time_range) VALUES (".$i.",'".$period_start."'::timestamp without time zone, '[".$period_start.",".$period_end.")'::tsrange );");    

$i++;
}
```

On the other side, I have a table which is supposed to contain the actual bookings from the users. Of course when a particular boat is booked, no one else should be able to book it at the same time.

The bookings table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE usg_bookings (
   id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sq$usg_bookings_id')
   , user_id INTEGER NOT NULL
   , boat_id INTEGER NOT NULL
   , start_time TIMESTAMP
   , time_range tsrange NOT NULL
);
```

With a sample looking like:

```
 id | user_id |   boat_id   |     start_time      |                  time_range
----+---------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------
  5 |       1 |           1 | 2017-02-11 08:00:00 | ["2017-02-11 08:00:00","2017-02-11 12:00:00")
  6 |       1 |           2 | 2017-02-11 13:00:00 | ["2017-02-11 13:00:00","2017-02-11 14:00:00")
  7 |       1 |           1 | 2017-02-14 09:00:00 | ["2017-02-14 09:00:00","2017-02-14 12:30:00")
  8 |       1 |           2 | 2017-02-14 13:30:00 | ["2017-02-14 13:30:00","2017-02-14 15:15:00")
```

To insert some dummy data in the bookings table:

```
INSERT INTO usg_bookings (user_id, group_id, boat_id, start_time,  time_range) VALUES
   (1,1,1, '2017-02-11 08:00:00'::timestamp, '["2017-02-11 08:00:00","2017-02-11 12:00:00")'::tsrange) 
  ,(1,1,2, '2017-02-11 13:00:00'::timestamp, '["2017-02-11 13:00:00","2017-02-11 14:00:00")'::tsrange)
  ,(1,1,1, '2017-02-14 09:00:00'::timestamp, '["2017-02-14 09:00:00","2017-02-14 12:30:00")'::tsrange) 
  ,(1,1,2, '2017-02-14 13:30:00'::timestamp, '["2017-02-14 13:30:00","2017-02-14 15:15:00")'::tsrange);
```

In my approach I use the "start_time" column for partitioning purpose and it is not intended to be used to query the tables. But it could change following yours advices :)

So I am looking for an efficient way to find the "gaps" between the bookings already recorded to be able to propose my users the best availability.

It should say: "There is a two hour availability next week for that particular boat".

Please note that I have some database and SQL experience but I am totally new to the concept of time ranges in PostgreSQL.

I thank you very much in advance for your great answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you take a different approach to this issue. For starters, the `cal_calendar` is not necessary and also the `start_time` field in table `usg_bookings` is redundant. Instead, work with the `tsrange` and use a window function to identify available periods. Also, set an `EXCLUDE` constraint on your table to avoid double bookings (in a web application you might get multiple people trying to book a boat at the same time; in the time it takes to identify an available rental and completing the rental itself (fill in name, credit card details, ...) someone else may have completed a booking for the same period and boat).

Your table becomes:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

CREATE TABLE usg_bookings (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   user_id integer NOT NULL,
   boat_id integer NOT NULL,
   time_range tsrange NOT NULL,
   EXCLUDE USING gist (boat_id WITH =, time_range WITH &&)
);
```

Find available periods for all boats:

```
SELECT boat_id, available
FROM (
    SELECT boat_id,
           tsrange(upper(time_range), lower(lead(time_range) OVER 
               (PARTITION BY boat_id ORDER BY lower(time_range)))) AS available
    FROM (
        SELECT boat_id, time_range
        FROM usg_bookings
        WHERE lower(time_range)::date BETWEEN <<<start_date>>> AND <<<final_date>>>
        UNION
        SELECT boat_id,
               tsrange(closed + interval '16 hours', closed + interval '32 hours')
        FROM generate_series(<<<start_date>>> - 1, <<<final_date>>>) dates(closed),
             VALUES(<<<boat ids>>>) b(boat_id) ) sub2
    ) sub
WHERE upper(available) - lower(available) >= interval '3 hours';
```

**Some explanation:**

You want to find boats available for at least 3 hours during day time hours (presuming your operation is closed from 4pm to 8am) over a defined period of time. The defined period of time is represented by `<<<start_date>>>` and `<<<final_date>>>` in the query. Since you are developing a web application, I presume you will use positional parameters in whatever framework you are using.

You do not want to make bookings when your operation is closed, so black out these hours. Effectively for the query, this is the same as having all boats rented out at all out-of-office hours:

```
SELECT boat_id,
       tsrange(closed + interval '16 hours', closed + interval '32 hours')
FROM generate_series(<<<start_date>>> - 1, <<<final_date>>>) dates(closed),
     VALUES(<<<boat ids>>>) b(boat_id)
```

In short, generate a series of days for each of the boats and block out from 4pm on the day until 8 am the next day (= 32 hours). Note that `start_date - 1` covers the period of midnight to 8am on the first day.

If you have a few boats, the `VALUES` clause is fine. If there are many boats or you might add or remove boats over time, use a sub-query like `SELECT DISTINCT boat_id FROM boats`.

This block-out list is merged with the existing bookings in the period of interest:

```
SELECT boat_id, time_range
FROM usg_bookings
WHERE lower(time_range)::date BETWEEN <<<start_date>>> AND <<<final_date>>>
UNION
<<<closed hours>>>
```

When you order all of the above unavailable periods (existing bookings and closed hours) you can determine the available hours for each boat by using a window function partitioned by `boat_id` and subtract the end of the rental or the opening of the office from the start of the next rental or the office closing hour:

```
SELECT boat_id,
       tsrange(upper(time_range), lower(lead(time_range) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY boat_id ORDER BY lower(time_range)))) AS available
FROM 
    <<<inner query>>>
```

The rows are partitioned by `boat_id` (so all rows of unavailable periods are evaluated for each of the boat ids) and ordered by `lower(time_range)` (the start of the unavailable period). The `tsrange()` part then makes a new `timestamp` range from the end of the current rental or opening hour and the start of the next rental or closing hour (the `lead()` window function).

Finally, in the main query you select all of those `available` intervals that are at least 3 hours long (`WHERE upper(available) - lower(available) >= interval '3 hours'`), for each of the boats.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for. Your answer is clear and spot on.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Happy to help and sorry to keep you waiting for so long. But (little anecdote) I read your question at the airport of Seoul, wrote the answer on the plane to Manila, got home at 1am, finished off next day (today) and then sent it off (most of my answers have no exotic anecdotes accompanying them). And welcome to SO to you!

Comment: Haha! Thanks for taking the time to answer my question with so many details. Greetings from a belgian guy living in Switzerland.

Comment: I am a bit lost with the `select`queries mentioning the `VALUES` it fails and I can't find a reference in the Postgresql doc :)

Comment: `VALUES`is a regular SQL command with its own [doc page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html). A brief description of how to use it is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) (sub-section 3). In general, with a `VALUES` clause you create a row-source, just like any other table, view or sub-query and you use it in the same way. Obviously, this is only useful for small amounts of data (like an `INSERT` of a single row in a table), otherwise you'd use a regular sub-query.

Comment: Thanks a million, I did find and read the documentation and the part containing `VALUES` is now clear for me.
Two more things if I may.
The generate_series requires a third parameter apparently referenced as "step interval" in [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html). Is this correct? When this is solved, the query then complains about `ERROR:  range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound` am I missing something?
Thank you so much again for your precious answers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like this:

```
WITH param AS (
    SELECT '{1}'::int4[] AS boats, '["2017-02-11 08:00:00","2017-02-16 20:00:00")'::tsrange AS time, '03:00:00'::time as period
), periods AS (
        SELECT c.start_time, time_range,  boat_id
          FROM cal_calendar AS c
          JOIN param AS p ON (time_range <@ time)
          JOIN boats AS b ON (b.boat_id = ANY(p.boats) OR p.boats IS NULL)
         WHERE
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                  FROM usg_bookings AS u
                 WHERE u.boat_id = b.boat_id
                   AND c.time_range <@ u.time_range
            )
), avail AS ( 
        WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
                SELECT p.* , 1 AS level
                  FROM periods AS p, param
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1
                          FROM periods AS p2
                         WHERE p2.start_time + '15 min'::interval = p.start_time
                           AND p2.boat_id = p.boat_id
                )
                UNION ALL
                SELECT x.start_time, x.time_range + p.time_range, x.boat_id, level + 1
                  FROM x
                  JOIN periods AS p ON (
                           p.start_time = upper(x.time_range)
                           AND p.boat_id = x.boat_id)
        ) SELECT *
            FROM x
           WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT 1
                       FROM x AS x2
                      WHERE x.boat_id = x2.boat_id
                        AND x.start_time = x2.start_time
                        AND x2.level > x.level)
)
SELECT a.start_time, a.time_range, a.boat_id
  FROM avail AS a, param AS p 
 WHERE p.period <= upper(a.time_range) - lower(a.time_range)
 ORDER BY boat_id, start_time, time_range
```

`param` is parameters, you can set some boat as `{1,3}` or any AS NULL.

`periods` is all periods not including already reserved by `usg_booking`

`avail` is aqaliable grouped (in WITH RECRSIVE x) periods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: This answer may be functional but it is a really complex beast. How is anybody ever going to understand (and maintain) this?